# Unable to print list of abbreviations in my document

Tags: glossaries, warnings, acronyms

I have a master document with several chapters as separate tex files. I am trying to print the list of abbreviations using `glossaries` package. I am defining it in the preamble as follow and I am doing it after the using the `hyperref` package:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
```

Then, I define the acronyms that I want to use as follow:

```
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
```

Later in the document body, I do the following:

```
\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\pagestyle{empty}

\includepdf[pages=1]{CoverPage.pdf}
\cleardoublepage

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\cleardoublepage

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

\include{Chater1}

\cleardoublepage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\newpage 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

I try to compile in three steps in TexMaker:

1. I call `pdflatex` for the master document.
2. I call `makeglossaries` for the master document.
3. I call again `pdflatex` for the master document.

When I call `makeglossaries` command, I get the following warnings:

```
 1. Warning: File 'master.glo' is empty. Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'main'? Remember to use package option 'nomain' if you don't want to use the main glossary.

 2. Warning: File 'master.acn' is empty. Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'acronym'?
```

So can anyone help me with this problem? What I am getting a warning that the `.acn` file is empty?

**Note:**

1. I have all the packages up to date.
2. In the generated pdf file, the place where the list of abbreviations should be printed is always empty without even a title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, you have to use an acronym somewhere in the body. Just defining it with `\newacronym` won't work

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I tested what you said on a single document without any body and the list of acronyms was printed perfectly. But when I am using it in a complicated example like what I did it is not working and I am getting the warnings.

Comment: Use `\gls{la}` at the appropiate position

Comment: Perhaps you had something like `\glsall` in that other document?

Comment: No, I did not have `\glsall` in that document. But now I just used `\gls{la}` in one of the chapters and the warning was suppressed. And the list of abbreviations was printed.

Comment: Well, the acronym should appear then

Comment: I called now `glsaddall`, and all the abbreviations I defined where printed. Thanks for you help